# URL rewrite urls with file extensions

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, file-extension

Using IIS7.5 and ASP.net, I have the re-write rule:

```
<rewrite url="~/store/playgame/([0-9]+)/(.*)" to="~/handlers/storeGetPlayGameContent?p1=$1&amp;p2=$2" processing="stop"/>
```

This works fine for the URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1/store/playgame/1/c2runtime
Requested URL: http://127.0.0.1:80/handlers/storeGetPlayGameContent?p1=1&p2=c2runtime
```

But for the URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1/store/playgame/1/c2runtime.js
Requested URL: http://127.0.0.1:80/store/playgame/1/c2runtime.js
```

As you can see the requested URL is now incorrect.  Any URL with a file extension that is NOT `.aspx` will rewrite incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

In the default configuration, IIS will serve js files itself, without going through the ASP.Net framework.  This means that your rewriter is never consulted.  You have to add the js extension (along with any others you want to handle) to the handler mappings in the IIS management tool.